# DualChart with sap.viz.ui5.Combination

Tags: java, sapui5

I have a small Problem with my Chart.

[image]

As you can see the Chart displays numbers above each bar.

The code looks like the following:

```
oDualChart = new sap.viz.ui5.Combination(
      {
       //    id: "dualcombination",
          width : "90%",
           height : "550px",
          // legendDirection: 'left',
        //   setplotArea : combination,
         dataLabel : {visible : true,
             positionPreference : true,
             position : sap.viz.ui5.types. 
             Datalabel_position.outside
             },
```

Is there a method for sap.viz.ui5.Combination with which I can hide the numbers I don't want to have displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution:

```
oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
    plotArea: {
        dataLabel: { renderer: function(oConfig){
            if(oConfig.val === 0){
                oConfig.text = "";
            }
        } }
    }
});
```

This will hide all labels where value is 0.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comment! The Problem is, that if you look at the Chart you can see the numbers above each bar. I wrote it wrong. My apologies for that. My task is to make sure that the number 0 disappears from the chart. So I have to display only numbers which are bigger than 0.

Comment: Ok, now it´s more clear to me what you would like to achieve. So, is it an option to filter the "0 values"? Or shall the space in the diagram still be displayed but no label?

Comment: In this case it would be better to filter the "0 values".

Comment: Hi, I updated the solution. This will hide the labels for 0 values. After some thinking I guess filtering is not really possible here because you would loose the legend too and I don´t know a way of filtering only a single property but not the whole record.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the quick answer. How did you defined the oVizFrame and the oConfig ? Because, since they are not defined in my code, I cannot use them.

Comment: oVizFrame should be oDualChart in your case and oConfig is a method parameter of the renderer function which you don´t have to define. It is passed on runtime to your method. You can name it as you like.